# Load a function only if $(window).width() < 700

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function like this:

```
test()
$(window).resize(test)

function test() {
  if($(window).width() < 700) {
     //load my function only for the view < 700px 
  } 

  //else -> return to my desktop view ($(window).width() > 700), and remove the function used for < 700px
}
```

But I have a problem: one the function is loaded, it stays loaded whether the browser window is resized smaller or not.

Is there a way to only load a function if the window is < than 700px and completely remove it if the window is > than 700?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Whatever function you have should be the one that checks for viewport width before executing it’s inner logic, instead of the other wah round.

Comment: try to get an integer using  the window  offset width property instead.

Comment: In the else you should put the code that "unloads" whatever is loaded if width < 700

Comment: Be sure to declare your functions before you reference them.

Comment: How do you understand the `load` of function here? Is it possible the right term be `execute`? -- What do you mean with `return to my desktop view` ?

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "remove the function" - if you "remove" a *function* it can still be called and will give an error.  Looks like a terminology issue - what **exactly** is your "my function for the view < 700px".  Could probably be solved using css @media queries.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?